# ASP.NET Core distributed cache with Redis or SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, caching, redis, asp.net-core

I'm looking at using Redis or SQL Server for storing sessions in ASP.NET Core, and maybe some other caching needs. A few quick questions:

1. Are there any major differences with the two?
2. Redis is in-memory, is SQL Server also for this purpose, or does it store everything on disk?
3. Would the SQL Server Express -version be enough

Comment: Good read about the redis vs sql  distrubuted caching performance at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881953/redis-vs-sql-server-performance.
spoiler: sql wins for the listed particular case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be able to use sql server for session state but redis is purpose built to handle the session state. A SQL based database like SQL Server is likely an overkill for session state management. From a cost of computing a session state lookup, redis will be much cheaper and faster. Redis is lightweight, low latency and more scalable.

*Full disclosure, I worked in engineering both product at different times. I work on Redis in Redis Labs these days.*

Comment: Yes, but I will use a distributed cache for caching other stuff too :) Anyway, Express is quite lightweight also?

Comment: express is still sql server with a few of the wheels removed but I'd not say it is light weight. BTW - if you are looking for an option for windows you can use redis on docker. There are a few repos I'd recommend; the official redis repo: http://hub.docker.com/_/redis - the redis-enterprise repo (clustered redis running Redis Cloud by Redis Labs): http://hub.docker.com/r/redislabs/redis